# How to make viewDidLoad method of ViewController call only once?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uicontainerview

I created a  *Container View* in my application. The container view loads other **UIViewController** when user tabs on a **UITableviewCell** and other **UIViewController** gets loaded inside the Container View. I tried testing by inserting log messages on other ViewController class and found out each time ***viewDidLoad*** and ***ViewDidAppear*** method gets called which states those class gets instantiated everytime on cell tab.

But while studying about container view on the apple docs
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

I found **UITabBarController** also implements ContainerView and manages its **UIViewController** in array. I tried inspecting the log messages and found that ***viewDidLoad*** method gets called only one time and when we visit second time on the tab only ***viewDidAppear*** gets called. So i was really wondering what is the behind the scene things in this. Are they using UnWind segue(i guess not).

However i created container View Controller with follwing way following these tutorial:
https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Container-View-Controllers-Quickstart as

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    var activeViewController : UIViewController? {
        didSet{
            removeInactiveViewController(oldValue)
            updateActiveViewController()
        }
    }


    var cellTxtArrs = ["FIRST","SECOND","THIRD"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var tblView : UITableView = UITableView()
        tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 300 ,100)
        tblView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        tblView.scrollEnabled = false
        tblView.rowHeight = (30)
        self.view.addSubview(tblView)
        tblView.delegate = self
        tblView.dataSource = self
        tblView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")


    }



    func removeInactiveViewController(inactiveViewController:UIViewController?){


        if let inActiveVC = inactiveViewController{

            inActiveVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

            inActiveVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

            inActiveVC.removeFromParentViewController()

        }


    }


    func updateActiveViewController(){


        if let activeVC = activeViewController{

            //not necessary
            addChildViewController(activeVC)

            activeVC.view.frame = contentView.bounds

            contentView.addSubview(activeVC.view)

            activeVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)




        }


    }





    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}


extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate{

    //MARK:  table view data source methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //  cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 22)
        var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.000, green: 0.400, blue: 0.404, alpha: 1.00)
        cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.cellTxtArrs[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.cellTxtArrs.count

    }


    //MARK: - table view delegate methods

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var row = indexPath.row

        switch row {

        case 0:




                let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstVC") as! FirstViewController
                activeViewController = firstVC



        case 1:

                var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondVC") as! SecondViewController
                activeViewController = secondVC


        case 2:


                let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let thirdVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thirdVC") as! ThirdViewController
                activeViewController = thirdVC



        default:
            println("no index")


        }




    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab bar controller has an array of child controllers which persist when switching between them.

Basically what you need to do is:

- create a container to hold the child controllers (an array)
- add controller to the array if it does not exist
- reuse the controller from the array if it exists

I use this procedure in quite a few places.

Note this also works great with having navigation controllers in the content view but the navigation stack will persist as well which may not be a desired result. For instance if you have 3 tabs and the 1st tab is navigated to 2nd view controller it will stay on 2nd view controller even after switching to 3rd tab and back to the 1st one.

Comment: umm.yeah..that means i should instantiate view controller only once..not while  tapping on cell right?

Comment: Depends, you have all the power. You may persist if forever in the array and only instantiate it once. You may for instance remove it on memory warning. Remove it for a specific device... Anything you want. But yes, generally it is about instantiating it once and keep it for as long as possibly needing it.

Comment: oh..thanks really...one more question...will i have  issues later while instantiating it just once....or should i add some login to viewDidAppear method to make changes to other viewContreoller, since viewDidLoad is not calling?How should i manage the changes for them

Comment: View will appear or did appear should handle those

Answer (score 1):

Cache the inactive view controllers in an array after being allocated, and you'll call their `viewDidLoad` method only once.

Right now viewDidLoad is called because you're allocating a new view controller each time.

Comment: umm..should i cache the viewcontroller means...i should initialize them is viewDidLoad method???