# Why my ViewDidLoad Loads every time?

Tags: ios, viewdidload

I am Creating a App in which I implemented FB login. So i write a FBLogin button code in my ViewDidLoad in ViewController.m file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];

}
```

but when i ran this code. fb buttons appears in all pages of my app, it means my viewController.m ViewDidLoad method call every time.Why?
I am looking for solution last 4 hours but didnt get any result yet.
please help me out.

Comment: Do your view controllers inherit from this view controller? Also, without seeing more code, we can only take blind shots at it.

Comment: The view appearing in multiple pages is an indication of reuse of this class, not `viewDidLoad` being called multiple times

Comment: @Lord Zsolt- yes. my view controllers inherit from this view controller.

Comment: instantiating view controller only results calling viewdidLoad..so it means your current ViewController.m is instantiating somewhere..so figure out that

Comment: @anish - all my classes are inherit with this view controller. like interface contestViewController : ViewController. Can this be a reason for my error?

Comment: yeah..thats the point..so figureout the solution that helps instanitating view controller only once..one example is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699001/how-to-make-viewdidload-method-of-viewcontroller-residing-inside-containerview-c

Comment: @anish- thnx, I will post if i find any solution. thnx for your suggestions.

Comment: yeah..if you cant, try posting your project...we will give a try

Comment: never ask for +1 on SO..try to get it auto....but i will do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer for my question

I made a small mistake when i inherit all Other ViewControllers and main ViewController class with ViewController. i modified my code with

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController


 @end
```

instead of

```
 @interface ViewController : ViewController

 @end
```

and all other classes too like

```
   @interface homeViewController : UIViewController

   @interface contestViewController : UIViewController


   @interface menuViewController : UIViewController
```

etc.

This simply solved my question. thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

As you've said, your view controllers inherit from this view controller, thus every view controller who calls `[super viewDidLoad]` will execute this method. (The solution isn't the removal of the `super` call).

Instead of creating this ViewController and every other view controller inherit from this one you could:

- Create a `CommonViewController` which implements everything that is common between your view controllers
- Create a `FacebookLoginViewController` which also inherit from `CommonViewController`.

Thus, your inheritance tree would look like:

```
CommonViewController
      /          \
     /            \
    /              \
FacebookLoginVC    OtherViewControllers
```

Instead of:

```
ViewController (which is equivalent to FacebookViewController)
     |
     |
     |
OtherViewControllers
```